# Interrupt/Exception caught

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, cmake

```
mingw32-make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x61207374)
```

When I run `make` on the windows prompt I get this error. I saw an article that said it has to do with the order of the paths specified on the `Path` environment variable. I made sure that `MinGW/bin` is the first path on the list (because that is where I'm getting `mingw32-make` but nonetheless I still get this error.

It works on the Git Bash prompt but strangely not on this Windows command prompt.

Comment: Okay the problem goes away when I get rid of everything in the User `PATH` environment variable. I'll have to figure out what exactly was in the `PATH` that was messing with make.

Comment: I just faced this issue on Windows PowerShell, and I can confirm that `gmake` working on git bash but throwing error on PowerShell/CMD still holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had some paths in my `PATH` variable that conflicted with make. Taking them out solved the problem.