# Makefile Mingw32-make Interrupt/Exception

Tags: c++, cmd, makefile, sfml

Why do I get error message when using `mingw32-make` on Win10 cmd. here is my Makefile code

```
all: compile link

compile:
    g++ -I src/include -c main.cpp
link:
    g++ main.o -o main -L src/lib -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system
```

here is the output on cmd

```
D:\Devs\C++\T2>mingw32-make
g++ -I src/include -c main.cpp
mingw32-make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x00007FF89CC5F398)
```

but if run it manually and individually it compiles properly?

```
D:\Devs\C++\T2>g++ -I src/include -c main.cpp

D:\Devs\C++\T2>g++ main.o -o main -L src/lib -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system
```

No error, and when I run the the main.exe file, the updated code applies.

For further information, here the libraries version I'm using:

```
D:\Devs\C++\T2>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

D:\Devs\C++\T2>cmake --version
cmake version 3.20.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: You manually created your makefile. Why do you think cmake is relevant here?

Comment: I have noticed `mingw32-make` to be unreliable in general, and had more luck with the regular `make` installed from MSYS2.

Comment: Why are you showing the version of cmake here?  You're not using cmake as far as I can tell...?

Answer (score 1):

0xc0000005 is an Access Violation.  It's coming from mingw32-make.  I had hoped it might be a configuration error, or you might be able to fix it simply by reinstalling.  That appears not to be the case.

Look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/375029/make-interrupt-exception-caught) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851988/421195).

The answer in both cases was related to the Windows %PATH% string.  Specifically:

> https://superuser.com/questions/375029/make-interrupt-exception-caught
>
> this problem is apparently caused when the PATH variable contains
> parentheses (, ), as it does on Win Vista/7. Unfortunately, the
> available GNU for Windows is hopelessly outdated.
>
> My problem was fixed by forcing make use the correct shell: insert the
> following line at the beginning of your makefile.
>
> `SHELL=C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe`

Comment: PowerShell can also cause problems when quoting for whitespace in paths or when the full-path contains the `':'` as in `C:\\dir\\file.c` (which is the normal path-separator in Unix). Using `cmd.exe` is generally more reliable as that was what MinGW was geared toward.

Comment: However, if I make a change on my Makefile instead of using `all: compile link` I use `all: link compile`. No error and no changes will take places on my main.exe (perhaps because of the sequence). Also, I've checked and remove all parentheses in my USER VARIABLE PATH, and still get and `Interrupt/Exception` even on Cmd (run as administrator).

Comment: Parentheses ("()") was just ^ONE* of the issues with %PATH% that was mentioned.  "Spaces" (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)` vs. `C:\PROGRA~1`) and was another.  [This response](https://superuser.com/a/752428) mentioned conflicting MSYS distributions.  Read all the responses in both of these links: https://superuser.com/questions/375029/make-interrupt-exception-caught and https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851988/421195.  Please post back what you find.